# Find most general 3-tensor under given constraint?

Tags: tensors, conditional, expression-construction

Consider `A` to be a general $2\times 2\times 2$ tensor:

```
A = Table[ a[i,j,k], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}];
```

pictorially one can draw it as a node having three legs with indices:

[image]

Consider a contraction of four such tensors to a new $2\times 2\times 2\times 2$ tensor `B`

```
B = 
   Table[ Sum[A[[i1, i2, j1]] A[[i2, i3, j2]] A[[i3, i4, j3]] A[[i4, i1, j4]], 
         {i1, 1, 2}, {i2, 1, 2}, {i3, 1, 2}, {i4, 1, 2}], 
         {j1, 1, 2}, {j2, 1, 2}, {j3, 1, 2}, {j4, 1, 2}]
```

which pictorially is given by

[image]

Now I would like to determine the most general `A` such that `B` is the `KroneckerDelta[j1,j2,j3,j4]`. Naively, I would try to solve this as:

```
Solve[(B//Flatten) == 
  (Table[KroneckerDelta[j1, j2, j3, j4],
     {j1, 1, 2}, {j2, 1, 2}, {j3, 1, 2}, {j4, 1, 2}]//Flatten), Variables[A]]
```

However, for some reason this calculation takes a lot of time and never finishes. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better, faster way to determine the most general form of `A` with these properties? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Have you seen [symbolic tensors functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicTensors.html)?

Comment: @kirma Thank you for the link. While the functions listed there are helpful to better organize notation and contractions, unfortunately I could not find anything that would help with determining the specific class of tensors I am looking for.

Comment: I must say I'm not skilled on it, but this just came to my mind on the basis I saw it on release notes recently. I think Mr. Wolfram himself had some nice words of it (in comparison to doing manual grunt work) on some video - I hoped it would be helpful in this case, too.

Comment: @kirma yes, thank you, improving notation and contraction convenience is helpful as well of course.

Comment: 16 nonlinear equations and only 8 unknowns.... Maybe better to start with contraction of 3 tensors?

Comment: @yarchik Yes, this sounds sensible, I will try that next, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also obtain 96 families of solutions. I consider for simplicity a case when A is symmetric with respect of indices 1 and 2, i.e.

```
a[1, 1, 1] = xx;
a[1, 2, 1] = xy;
a[2, 2, 1] = yy;
a[1, 1, 2] = zz;
a[1, 2, 2] = zw;
a[2, 2, 2] = ww;
a[i_, j_, k_] := a[j, i, k];

A = Table[a[i, j, k], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}]
(*{{{xx, zz}, {xy, zw}}, {{xy, zw}, {yy, ww}}}*)
```

Thus we have **6** variables to solve for. Form B and check symmetry relations:

```
B = Table[Sum[A[[i1, i2, j1]] A[[i2, i3, j2]] A[[i3, i4, j3]] A[[i4,i1,j4]], {i1, 2}, {i2, 2}, {i3, 2}, {i4, 2}], {j1, 2}, {j2,2}, {j3, 2}, {j4, 2}]
B[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == B[[1, 1, 2, 1]]
B[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == B[[1, 2, 1, 1]]
B[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == B[[2, 1, 1, 1]]
(* True, True, True *)
B[[2, 2, 2, 1]] == B[[2, 2, 1, 2]]
B[[2, 2, 2, 1]] == B[[2, 1, 2, 2]]
B[[2, 2, 2, 1]] == B[[1, 2, 2, 2]]
(* True, True, True *)
B[[1, 1, 2, 2]] == B[[2, 1, 1, 2]]
B[[1, 1, 2, 2]] == B[[2, 2, 1, 1]]
B[[1, 1, 2, 2]] == B[[1, 2, 2, 1]]
(* True, True, True *)
B[[2, 1, 2, 1]] - B[[1, 2, 1, 2]]
(*True*)
```

10 Symmetry relations reduce the number to equations to **6**. Thus, number of unknowns is equal to the number of equations.

```
eqs = {B[[1, 1, 1, 1]] == 1 && B[[2, 2, 2, 2]] == 1 && 
B[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == 0 && B[[2, 2, 2, 1]] == 0 && 
B[[1, 1, 2, 2]] == 0 && B[[2, 1, 2, 1]] == 0}
```

There are 96 families of solutions:

```
sol = Solve[eqs, Variables[A]];
Length[sol]
(*96*)
```

When desired they can be plotted (there are 32 lines and 64 points) as follows:

```
 ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[{Re[ww], Im[ww]} /. (sol[[k]] /. xy -> t), {k,32}]], {t, 0,1.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[Table[{Re[ww], Im[ww]} /. sol[[k]], {k, 33, 96}]]}]
```

[image: 32 lines and 64 points]

Comment: This is awesome! I guess those families of solutions will be more than enough for me to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this gives an answer

```
FindInstance[(B //Flatten) == (Table[KroneckerDelta[j1, j2, j3, j4], {j1,2}, {j2,2}, {j3,2}, {j4,2}] // Flatten), Variables[A], Integers]

 (*{{a[1, 1, 1] -> 0, a[1, 1, 2] -> 1, a[1, 2, 1] -> 0, a[1, 2, 2] -> 0, a[2, 1, 1] -> 0, a[2, 1, 2] -> 0, a[2, 2, 1] -> 1, a[2, 2, 2] -> 0}}*)
```

Others should be possible to generate by permutations. However, it is not the case. Misspellings somewhere?

Comment: One can see that the solution found is of trivial kind where only two entries are non zero and equal to 1. I anticipate that a general solution should have continuous parameters and more than 2 entries non zero.